# How to check URLs in Ajax then fire an event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on one urlChecker tool where I need to check multiple URLs. If all URLs are UP then image should change to green ,if any of the url is down image should change to red. Below is my code ,don't know what's going wrong in it. It checks all URLs ,but its failed to show red image if any of URL is down.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script> 
    var urlArray = Array();
    urlArray[0] = 'http://google.com';
    urlArray[1] = 'm';
    urlArray[2] = 'http://apple.com';

    $(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < urlArray.length; i++) {
            urlcheck(i);
        }
    })

    function urlcheck(i) {
        var url1 = urlArray[i];


        $(document).ready(function() {

            var urlExists = function(url, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'HEAD',
                    url: url,
                    success: function() {
                        callback(true);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        callback(false);
                    }
                });
            }

            urlExists(url1, function(success) {
                if (success) {
                    //alert('Success!');
                    $("#theImg").attr("src", "images/green.png")

                } else {
                    //alert('Down!');
                    $("#theImg").attr("src", "images/red.png")
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>

</head>

<body>


 <form name=form01>

            <td style="height: 60px;; width: 75px"><IMG 
                ID="theImg" border="0" src="images/wait.png" width="40"
                height="40"></IMG></td>
            </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should post your code as snippet, both JS and HTML.

Comment: @camelsWriteInCamelCase Hi I have edited my code and added html also. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please try this out

```
$(function () {
    var urlArray = Array();
    urlArray[0] = 'http://google.com';
    urlArray[1] = 'http://m';
    urlArray[2] = 'http://apple.com';
    var url_flag = 0;

    $(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < urlArray.length; i++) {
            urlcheck(i);
        }
    })

    function urlcheck(i) {
        var url1 = urlArray[i];

        $(document).ready(function () {
           //Set the green image as default
           $("#theImg").attr("src", "images/green.png")

            var urlExists = function (url, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'HEAD', url: url, success: function () {
                        callback(true);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        callback(false);
                    }
                });
            }

            urlExists(url1, function (success) {
                if (!success) {
                    url_flag = 1;

                    setImage(url_flag);
                }

            });

        });
    }

    function setImage(url_flag){
        if (url_flag == 1) {
            $("#theImg").attr("src", "http://s1.thingpic.com/images/2T/1SL9eAWko9U1ZhnPvMvAzvw2.png")
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Hi hari, Somewhere it is close to . it is working fine for if any one url is down but not fine for if all urls are up. If all urls are UP its not showing green image. May be if(!success) { url flag =1; else url_flag=0 and call setImage fun. I did like this and it worked for all.

Comment: @Pankaj_Dwivedi have made an edit to the post, just set the green image as default inside the ready function, and only update the image if any of the url returns false

Answer (score 0):

Should be ok :

```
var urlArray = Array();
urlArray[0] = 'http://google.com';
urlArray[1] = 'm';
urlArray[2] = 'http://apple.com';

function handler(status){
   var img = '';
   if(!!status){
     img = "images/green.png";
   }else{
     img = "images/red.png";
   }
   $("#theImg").attr("src",img);
}

function checkUrls (arr) {
    var len = arr.length;
    urlArray.map(function (url) {
       ping(url)
       .done(function(){
           if(--len === 0) handler(true);
       })
       .fail(function(){
           handler(false);
       })
    })
}

function ping (url) {
    return $.ajax({ 
      type: "HEAD",
      url: url,
      cache:false
    })
}

checkUrls(urlArray);
```

Comment: You have a syntax error somewhere, but I also think this should work.

Comment: Missing ")" after argument list

Comment: "Success is not a function"

Comment: I also couldn't remember the name, I know about done but not this one. It would probably work, but the fiddle I'm running it on refuses to put an ajax request on google from some reason, this is most likely not your fault.

Comment: Yes, i think you can't do whatever you want on jsFiddle

Comment: Why the double `!!`?  Since if casts it automatically to bool you could just do without it.

Comment: habitude, but yes, you don't need it. Should have better perf in another case (?)